# facebook change default og:url and canonical URL with metatags module

Tags: 7, meta-tags, social-network, uri

I moved my site from HTTP to HTTPS, now a few days later my facebook likes are waaay lower.
For example one article under HTTP was 25K likes now under HTTPS it is 3K likes. I am face with the facebook likes count discrepancy and refer to [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_1149655968420144) page to try to fix it. I removed the og:url content : `[current-page:url:absolute]` from the metatag [config page](https://mediamatters.org/admin/config/search/metatags/config/node) and manually updated the og:url. I also removed the canonical URL `[current-page:url:absolute]`  from the metatag as facebook is using it but facebook is still seeing the HTTPS likes  not the HTTP likes for old content.
I also tried `http://example.com[current-page:url:relative]` without success.
Is there a way in metatag module to have the canonical URL to point to HTTP and not HTTPS by changing `[current-page:url:absolute]` for canonical URL?
How to make Facebook not see the 301 HTTP Redirect and stick to old url?

Comment: This is more or less a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27261781/switching-from-http-to-https-lost-all-facebook-likes-count. I suppose setting `og:url` to `http://example.com[current-page:url:relative]` should be the way to, but apparently it takes some time befor facebook detects the change.